# Create div X number of time from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create div using javascript and jquery.

My Code so far:

```
<script>
var numOfWindows = 3;

var arrayDiv = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < numOfWindows; i++)
{
    var newDiv = $('#server div:first').clone();
   $('#server').append(newDiv);
}
</script>


<input type="text" name="numserver"><br>
<button onclick="new_server()">GO</button>
<br>

<div id="server">
<div id="1">
<table border="3"><tbody>
<tr><th colspan="4" style="background-color:#b0c4de;">Server 1</th></tr>
<br>
<tr><td>Technology<select name="tech[]"><option value="w">Web</option><option value="d">DB</option><option value="m">Mail</option><option     value="o">Other</option></select><br>
<br></td>
<td>CPU? <input type="text" name="cpu[]"><br></td>
<td>Memory? <input type="text" name="memory[]"><br></td>
<td>Disk Space? <input type="text" name="space[]"><br></td></tr>
<br>
</tbody></table>
</div>
</div>
```

My end result is for the user to be able to enter the amount of servers and click GO and then the divs are automatically created.

I know how to get the  numOfWindows value but i think it should work with a static value for now.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because you placed the script before the elements in the DOM without a DOM ready handler. Wen you're cloning and appending, there are no elements available to clone or append to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct, but how says adeneo, you don't have a DOM ready handler.
Use instead something like this:

```js
function LoadMyJs(){
  var numOfWindows = 3;

  var arrayDiv = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < numOfWindows; i++)
  {
    var newDiv = $('#server div:first').clone();
    $('#server').append(newDiv);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="LoadMyJs()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run the script which works with undefined HTML. To solve this you can either move your script after defining HTML or use jquery shortcut document.ready function such as `$(function(){<your code here>});`.

In first case event handler has to be a global variable right away. Otherwise you declare this variable before shortcut scope.

Next you define that event handler function obtains `input` value (`$('input[name="numserver"]').val()`). And now you can generate as many divs as defined by the value(`Array.apply(null, [+value]).map(function(){<generator here>})`). To generate copies clone method may be used and generated divs should be inserted into div container as you do.

Looks like you're trying to generate divs by "GO" button click. In your case to do that event handler function should be named "new_server". And you don't call this function in "onclick" attribute you just declare it.